# Searching with space not working on specific field by Query String

Tags: search, elasticsearch, elastica

Searching "follow back" in Twitter User's description field that I have indexed already with following mapping.

Note: Only Highlight some of mapping.

1.

```
'analysis' => array(
        'analyzer' => array(    
                'myanalyzer' => array(
                        "type"  =>  "standard",
                        'stopwords' => '_none_',
                ),
        )
  )
```

2.

```
$mapping->setParam('index_analyzer', 'myanalyzer'); 
$mapping->setParam('search_analyzer', 'myanalyzer');
```

3.

```
'description'  => array('type' => 'string', "index" => "not_analyzed"),
```

4.

```
//search something
$queryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
$queryString->setDefaultOperator( "AND" );  
// $queryString->setFields(array("user.description"));
$queryString->setQuery('follow back');
```

When Searched while setFields is commented it gives me lot of results like

> IF YOU FOLLOW ILL FOLLOW BACK! :) 100% follow back! :)
>
> Follow me i follow back :) instagram:juliemar25 i follow back

But after uncomment **setFields** and **defaultOperator** to **AND**, then it show no results.
AND by uncomment **setFields** and **defaultOperator** to **OR**, it shows me only results that have **"follow"** in description nothing else.

Q1: Why white space not working on setFields instead working with _all?

While Using Match Query

```
$matchQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$matchfield = "user.description";
$queryToMatch = "follow back";

$matchQuery->setFieldQuery($matchfield, $queryToMatch);
```

It also show only two results that have **"follow back"** only in description. But after changing to match field to **_all** it show lot of results that contains **"follow back"** in description field

Q2. Why it is happening? How can I search for space separated words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set  "description" field to be not_analyzed as per the mapping above.

This would result in the description field payload  being indexed as is and a match occurs when the 'description' field is an  exact search phrase which in this case is "follow back"

Removing "index" => "not_analyzed" should fix it.

Comment: At this situation I have to use exact match with phrase using MathcQuery?

Its mean QueryString work on terms (analyzed) fields only?

Comment: Thanks @keety after re-indexing with description analyzed above problems solved.

But now with mathQuery if I enable matchType Phrase and search for phrase it gives me 

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elastica\Exception\PartialShardFailureException' with message '1' in F:\wamp\www\zendProjects10\elasticsearch\ES\Elastica\Transport\Http.php on line 154**

Comment: Another Question please. How can I search for "follow bac" as here back is lake of k. Its doesn't match any thing. Which method I have to use for it? Thanks